# PyTorch Lightning - How can I output a summary of training to the console

Tags: pytorch-lightning

PyTorch Lighting can log to TensorBoard.  How can I make it log to the console a table summarizing the training runs (similar to Huggingface's Transformers, shown below):

```
Epoch   Training Loss   Validation Loss Runtime Samples Per Second
1   1.220600    1.160322    39.574900   272.496000
2   0.945200    1.121690    39.706000   271.596000
3   0.773000    1.157358    39.734000   271.405000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own callback function and add it into the trainer.

```
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_info

class LoggingCallback(pl.Callback):

    def on_validation_end(self, trainer: pl.Trainer, pl_module: pl.LightningModule):
        rank_zero_info("***** Test results *****")
        metrics = trainer.callback_metrics
        # Log results
        for key in sorted(metrics):
            if key not in ["log", "progress_bar"]:
                rank_zero_info("{} = {}\n".format(key, str(metrics[key])))
```

Example for adding it to trainer:

```
logging_callback = LoggingCallback()
trainer = pl.Trainer.from_argparse_args(
        args,
        callbacks=[logging_callback],
        )
```

Comment: How do we add it into the trainer?

Comment: See the update. You can add it to the trainer as usual callbacks.